# Why are the icon classes not getting changed when using event listeners to detect changes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I was trying to do my own take of this: https://codepen.io/codifiedconcepts/pen/bwgxRq

I've made a few tweaks, but when I change the time in the drop-downs, the icons don't change as intended. I've tested it by manually changing the time and the icons changed, and I've tested the event listeners by adding an alert box - everything is fine.

But when I go to change on the drop-down themselves, the icons don't change. I just can't seem to get it to work.

```js
  let wakeTime = 7;
    let noon = 12;
    let lunch = 12;
    let evening = 17;
    let dinner = 18;
    let bed = 21;
    
    
    //Setting time up 
    let showCurrentTime = () => {
        const clock = document.getElementById('clock');
        let currentTime = new Date();
        let hours = currentTime.getHours();
        let minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        let seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        let meridian = "AM";
    
             if (hours >= noon)
          {
              meridian = "PM";
          }
    
          if (hours > noon)
          {
              hours = hours - 12;
          }
     
        // Set Minutes
        if (minutes < 10)
        {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
     
        // Set Seconds
        if (seconds < 10)
        {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }
            //Putting it all together 
            let clockTime = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}  ${meridian}!`;
            clock.innerText = clockTime;
    };
    
    
    
    //Getting the clock to update on its own so it changes pictures and messages
    let updateClock = () => {
        let time = new Date().getHours();
        let message = document.getElementById('message');
        let icon = document.getElementById('food-icon');
    
        if(time === wakeTime){
            icon.classList.remove('fa-smile');
            icon.classList.add('fa-clock');
            message.textContent = 'Wakey wakey!';
        } else if (time === lunch){
            icon.classList.remove('fa-smile');
            icon.classList.add('fa-hotdog');
            message.textContent = "I'm hungry."
        } else if (time === dinner ) {
            icon.classList.remove('fa-smile');
            icon.classList.add('fa-utensils');
            message.textContent = "Can I have more food?";
        } else if (time === bed){
            icon.classList.remove('fa-smile');
            icon.classList.add('fa-bed');
            message.textContent = "YAWN";
        } else if (time >= noon ) {
            icon.classList.add('fa-smile');
            message.textContent = "Good afternoon!"
        } else if (time < noon) {
            icon.classList.add('fa-smile');
            message.innerHtml = "Good morning!";
        } else if (time >= evening) {
            icon.classList.add('fa-smile');
            message.textContent = "Good evening!";
        }
        showCurrentTime();
    };
    updateClock();
    
    //Getting the clock to increment once a second
    const oneSecond = 1000;
    setInterval(updateClock, oneSecond);
    
    const wakeSelect = document.querySelector('#wakeSelect')
    wakeSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
        wakeTime = wakeSelect.value;
    });
    
    const lunchSelect = document.querySelector('#lunchSelect')
    lunchSelect.addEventListener('change', () => {
        lunch = lunchSelect.value;
    });
    
    const dinnerSelect = document.querySelector('#dinnerSelect')
    dinnerSelect.addEventListener('change', () => {
        dinner = dinnerSelect.value;
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Vanilla JS Clock</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35e4240984.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        
        <h1>What time is it!?</h1>
        <span id="clock">Clock goes here</span>
        
        <div class="icon-wrapper">
        <i id="food-icon" class="fa-5x fas"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="message">
            <p>Hello!</p>
        </div>

        <label>Choose wake up time:</label>
        <select id="wakeSelect">
            <option value="1">1 AM</option>
            <option value="2">2 AM</option>
            <option value="3">3 AM - 4AM</option>
            <option value="4">4 AM - 5AM</option>
            <option value="5">5 AM - 6AM</option>
            <option value="6">6 AM - 7AM</option>
            <option value="7">7 AM - 8AM</option>
            <option value="8" selected>8 AM - 9AM</option>
            <option value="9">9 AM - 10AM</option>
            <option value="10">10 AM - 11AM</option>
            <option value="11">11 AM - 12PM</option>
            <option value="12">12 PM - 1PM</option>
            <option value="13">1 PM - 2PM</option>
            <option value="14">2 PM - 3PM</option>
            <option value="15">3 PM - 4PM</option>
            <option value="16">4 PM - 5PM</option>
            <option value="17">5 PM - 6PM</option>
            <option value="18">6 PM - 7PM</option>
            <option value="19">7 PM - 8PM</option>
            <option value="20">8 PM - 9PM</option>
            <option value="21">9 PM - 10PM</option>
            <option value="22">10 PM - 11PM</option>
            <option value="23">11 PM - 12AM</option>
            <option value="24">12 AM - 1AM</option>
          </select>
        
         <label for="lunchSelect">Choose lunch time</label> 
            <select id="lunchSelect">
              <option value="1">1 AM - 2AM</option>
              <option value="2">2 AM - 3AM</option>
              <option value="3">3 AM - 4AM</option>
              <option value="4">4 AM - 5AM</option>
              <option value="5">5 AM - 6AM</option>
              <option value="6">6 AM - 7AM</option>
              <option value="7">7 AM - 8AM</option>
              <option value="8">8 AM - 9AM</option>
              <option value="9">9 AM - 10AM</option>
              <option value="10">10 AM - 11AM</option>
              <option value="11">11 AM - 12PM</option>
              <option value="12" selected>12 PM - 1PM</option>
              <option value="13">1 PM - 2PM</option>
              <option value="14">2 PM - 3PM</option>
              <option value="15">3 PM - 4PM</option>
              <option value="16">4 PM - 5PM</option>
              <option value="17">5 PM - 6PM</option>
              <option value="18">6 PM - 7PM</option>
              <option value="19">7 PM - 8PM</option>
              <option value="20">8 PM - 9PM</option>
              <option value="21">9 PM - 10PM</option>
              <option value="22">10 PM - 11PM</option>
              <option value="23">11 PM - 12AM</option>
              <option value="24">12 AM - 1AM</option>
            </select>

      

            <label>Choose dinner time</label> 
            <select id="dinnerSelect">
              <option value="1">1 AM - 2AM</option>
              <option value="2">2 AM - 3AM</option>
              <option value="3">3 AM - 4AM</option>
              <option value="4">4 AM - 5AM</option>
              <option value="5">5 AM - 6AM</option>
              <option value="6">6 AM - 7AM</option>
              <option value="7">7 AM - 8AM</option>
              <option value="8">8 AM - 9AM</option>
              <option value="9">9 AM - 10AM</option>
              <option value="10">10 AM - 11AM</option>
              <option value="11">11 AM - 12PM</option>
              <option value="12">12 PM - 1PM</option>
              <option value="13">1 PM - 2PM</option>
              <option value="14">2 PM - 3PM</option>
              <option value="15">3 PM - 4PM</option>
              <option value="16">4 PM - 5PM</option>
              <option value="17">5 PM - 6PM</option>
              <option value="18" selected>6 PM &ndash; 7PM</option>
              <option value="19">7 PM - 8PM</option>
              <option value="20">8 PM - 9PM</option>
              <option value="21">9 PM - 10PM</option>
              <option value="22">10 PM - 11PM</option>
              <option value="23">11 PM - 12AM</option>
              <option value="24">12 AM - 1AM</option>
            </select>
 
   
        <script src="index.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest taking a look at how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that only includes the minimum amount of code to show the problem. the less code we have to go through, the quicker & easier it is for us so you are more likely to get help you need )

Comment: In `updateClock` function, in each `if` block you need to `remove('fa-...')` not only 'fa-smile', but all others, 'fa-hotdog' etc. To clear the previous icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to compare variables of different types using `===` which **compares the values *and* the data type**. So when you were doing this in `updateClock`:

```
if(time === wakeTime)
```

it was failing even if the values were the same because `time` is a number and `wakeTime` is a string. There are 2 ways you can change the code to fix this:

1. **Compare the values *only*** and not the types using `==` : `if(time == wakeTime)`
2. Or **change the string to a number** using the `Number` or `parseInt` functions, e.g. `if(time === Number(wakeTime))`

I've changed this below in your `updateClock` function, you can see it working here! I've also fixed the incorrect icon classes not being removed (see the update below):

```js
let wakeTime = 7;
    let noon = 12;
    let lunch = 12;
    let evening = 17;
    let dinner = 18;
    let bed = 21;
    
    
    //Setting time up 
    let showCurrentTime = () => {
        const clock = document.getElementById('clock');
        let currentTime = new Date();
        let hours = currentTime.getHours();
        let minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        let seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        let meridian = "AM";
    
             if (hours >= noon)
          {
              meridian = "PM";
          }
    
          if (hours > noon)
          {
              hours = hours - 12;
          }
     
        // Set Minutes
        if (minutes < 10)
        {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
     
        // Set Seconds
        if (seconds < 10)
        {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }
            //Putting it all together 
            let clockTime = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}  ${meridian}!`;
            clock.innerText = clockTime;
    };
    
    
    //Getting the clock to update on its own so it changes pictures and messages
    let updateClock = () => {
        let time = new Date().getHours();
        let message = document.getElementById('message');
        let icon = document.getElementById('food-icon');

        if(time == wakeTime){
            changeIcon(icon, 'fa-clock');
            message.textContent = 'Wakey wakey!';
        } else if (time == lunch){
            changeIcon(icon, 'fa-hotdog');
            message.textContent = "I'm hungry."
        } else if (time == dinner ) {
            changeIcon(icon, 'fa-utensils');
            message.textContent = "Can I have more food?";
        } else if (time == bed){
            changeIcon(icon, 'fa-bed');
            message.textContent = "YAWN";
        } else if (time >= noon ) {
            changeIcon(icon, 'fa-smile');
            message.textContent = "Good afternoon!"
        } else if (time < noon) {
            changeIcon(icon, 'fa-smile');
            message.innerHtml = "Good morning!";
        } else if (time >= evening) {
            changeIcon(icon, 'fa-smile');
            message.textContent = "Good evening!";
        }
        showCurrentTime();
    };
    updateClock();
    
    //Getting the clock to increment once a second
    const oneSecond = 1000;
    setInterval(updateClock, oneSecond);
    
    const wakeSelect = document.querySelector('#wakeSelect')
    wakeSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
        wakeTime = wakeSelect.value;
    });
    
    const lunchSelect = document.querySelector('#lunchSelect')
    lunchSelect.addEventListener('change', () => {
        lunch = lunchSelect.value;
    });
    
    const dinnerSelect = document.querySelector('#dinnerSelect')
    dinnerSelect.addEventListener('change', () => {
        dinner = dinnerSelect.value;
    });
    
function changeIcon(iconElement, newIconClass){
    // remove all existing icon classes 
    iconElement.classList.forEach(className => {
        // check for classes starting with "fa-" but are not "fa-5x"
        if (className.startsWith('fa-') && className!=('fa-5x')) 
            iconElement.classList.remove(className);
    });
    // now add the new class
    iconElement.classList.add(newIconClass);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35e4240984.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h1>What time is it!?</h1>
        <span id="clock">Clock goes here</span>
        
        <div class="icon-wrapper">
        <i id="food-icon" class="fa-5x fas"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="message">
            <p>Hello!</p>
        </div>

        <label>Choose wake up time:</label>
        <select id="wakeSelect">
            <option value="1">1 AM</option>
            <option value="2">2 AM</option>
            <option value="3">3 AM - 4AM</option>
            <option value="4">4 AM - 5AM</option>
            <option value="5">5 AM - 6AM</option>
            <option value="6">6 AM - 7AM</option>
            <option value="7">7 AM - 8AM</option>
            <option value="8" selected>8 AM - 9AM</option>
            <option value="9">9 AM - 10AM</option>
            <option value="10">10 AM - 11AM</option>
            <option value="11">11 AM - 12PM</option>
            <option value="12">12 PM - 1PM</option>
            <option value="13">1 PM - 2PM</option>
            <option value="14">2 PM - 3PM</option>
            <option value="15">3 PM - 4PM</option>
            <option value="16">4 PM - 5PM</option>
            <option value="17">5 PM - 6PM</option>
            <option value="18">6 PM - 7PM</option>
            <option value="19">7 PM - 8PM</option>
            <option value="20">8 PM - 9PM</option>
            <option value="21">9 PM - 10PM</option>
            <option value="22">10 PM - 11PM</option>
            <option value="23">11 PM - 12AM</option>
            <option value="24">12 AM - 1AM</option>
          </select>
        
         <label for="lunchSelect">Choose lunch time</label> 
            <select id="lunchSelect">
              <option value="1">1 AM - 2AM</option>
              <option value="2">2 AM - 3AM</option>
              <option value="3">3 AM - 4AM</option>
              <option value="4">4 AM - 5AM</option>
              <option value="5">5 AM - 6AM</option>
              <option value="6">6 AM - 7AM</option>
              <option value="7">7 AM - 8AM</option>
              <option value="8">8 AM - 9AM</option>
              <option value="9">9 AM - 10AM</option>
              <option value="10">10 AM - 11AM</option>
              <option value="11">11 AM - 12PM</option>
              <option value="12" selected>12 PM - 1PM</option>
              <option value="13">1 PM - 2PM</option>
              <option value="14">2 PM - 3PM</option>
              <option value="15">3 PM - 4PM</option>
              <option value="16">4 PM - 5PM</option>
              <option value="17">5 PM - 6PM</option>
              <option value="18">6 PM - 7PM</option>
              <option value="19">7 PM - 8PM</option>
              <option value="20">8 PM - 9PM</option>
              <option value="21">9 PM - 10PM</option>
              <option value="22">10 PM - 11PM</option>
              <option value="23">11 PM - 12AM</option>
              <option value="24">12 AM - 1AM</option>
            </select>

      

            <label>Choose dinner time</label> 
            <select id="dinnerSelect">
              <option value="1">1 AM - 2AM</option>
              <option value="2">2 AM - 3AM</option>
              <option value="3">3 AM - 4AM</option>
              <option value="4">4 AM - 5AM</option>
              <option value="5">5 AM - 6AM</option>
              <option value="6">6 AM - 7AM</option>
              <option value="7">7 AM - 8AM</option>
              <option value="8">8 AM - 9AM</option>
              <option value="9">9 AM - 10AM</option>
              <option value="10">10 AM - 11AM</option>
              <option value="11">11 AM - 12PM</option>
              <option value="12">12 PM - 1PM</option>
              <option value="13">1 PM - 2PM</option>
              <option value="14">2 PM - 3PM</option>
              <option value="15">3 PM - 4PM</option>
              <option value="16">4 PM - 5PM</option>
              <option value="17">5 PM - 6PM</option>
              <option value="18" selected>6 PM &ndash; 7PM</option>
              <option value="19">7 PM - 8PM</option>
              <option value="20">8 PM - 9PM</option>
              <option value="21">9 PM - 10PM</option>
              <option value="22">10 PM - 11PM</option>
              <option value="23">11 PM - 12AM</option>
              <option value="24">12 AM - 1AM</option>
            </select>
```

**Note**: you have other problems with your logic removing your icons. For example you are only removing the `fa-smile` class from `if (time==wakeTime)` so if you changed lunch time for example, then the icon would be something else and you are not removing it. You can change it so that it removes all existing classes instead of specific ones.

**UPDATE - remove *all* existing `fa-` icon classes:**

The most flexible way to do this is probably to remove any icon classes starting with `fa-`, so you don't have to keep a list.

The following function looks for all classes starting with `fa-` *except* `fa-5x` (because you need that for the size), and removes them. You can also pass in the new icon class:

```
function changeIcon(iconElement, newIconClass){
    // remove all existing icon classes 
    iconElement.classList.forEach(className => {
        // check for classes starting with "fa-" but are not "fa-5x"
        if (className.startsWith('fa-') && className!=('fa-5x')) 
            iconElement.classList.remove(className);
    });
    // now add the new class
    iconElement.classList.add(newIconClass);
}
```

To use it, you just need to do the following!

```
if(time == wakeTime){
    changeIcon(icon, 'fa-clock');
    message.textContent = 'Wakey wakey!';
}
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I've applied 2 changes to your code:

1. `wakeTime = parseInt(wakeSelect.value);` parse to int, since you are cmparing with `===` (other values aswell)
2. Remove ALL the set classes in class list by listing all possible in advance:
   `const classes = ['fa-smile', 'fa-clock', 'fa-hotdog', 'fa-utensils', 'fa-bed'];`
   then removing them before a new one gets set `icon.classList.remove(...classes);` you can call this outside the if/else block. But I'll leave that to you :)

```js
let wakeTime = 7;
    let noon = 12;
    let lunch = 12;
    let evening = 17;
    let dinner = 18;
    let bed = 21;
    
    
    //Setting time up 
    let showCurrentTime = () => {
        const clock = document.getElementById('clock');
        let currentTime = new Date();
        let hours = currentTime.getHours();
        let minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        let seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        let meridian = "AM";
    
             if (hours >= noon)
          {
              meridian = "PM";
          }
    
          if (hours > noon)
          {
              hours = hours - 12;
          }
     
        // Set Minutes
        if (minutes < 10)
        {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
     
        // Set Seconds
        if (seconds < 10)
        {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }
            //Putting it all together 
            let clockTime = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}  ${meridian}!`;
            clock.innerText = clockTime;
    };
    
    
    
    //Getting the clock to update on its own so it changes pictures and messages
    let updateClock = () => {
        let time = new Date().getHours();
        let message = document.getElementById('message');
        let icon = document.getElementById('food-icon');
        const classes = ['fa-smile', 'fa-clock', 'fa-hotdog', 'fa-utensils', 'fa-bed'];
        
       
        if(time === wakeTime){
            icon.classList.remove(...classes);
            icon.classList.add('fa-clock');
            message.textContent = 'Wakey wakey!';
        } else if (time === lunch){
            icon.classList.remove(...classes);
            icon.classList.add('fa-hotdog');
            message.textContent = "I'm hungry."
        } else if (time === dinner ) {
            icon.classList.remove(...classes);
            icon.classList.add('fa-utensils');
            message.textContent = "Can I have more food?";
        } else if (time === bed){
            icon.classList.remove(...classes);
            icon.classList.add('fa-bed');
            message.textContent = "YAWN";
        } else if (time >= noon ) {
            icon.classList.remove(...classes);
            icon.classList.add('fa-smile');
            message.textContent = "Good afternoon!"
        } else if (time < noon) {
            icon.classList.remove(...classes);
            icon.classList.add('fa-smile');
            message.innerHtml = "Good morning!";
        } else if (time >= evening) {
            icon.classList.remove(...classes);
            icon.classList.add('fa-smile');
            message.textContent = "Good evening!";
        }
        showCurrentTime();
    };
    updateClock();
    
    //Getting the clock to increment once a second
    const oneSecond = 1000;
    setInterval(updateClock, oneSecond);
    
    const wakeSelect = document.querySelector('#wakeSelect')
    wakeSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
        wakeTime = parseInt(wakeSelect.value);
    });
    
    const lunchSelect = document.querySelector('#lunchSelect')
    lunchSelect.addEventListener('change', () => {
        lunch = parseInt(lunchSelect.value);
    });
    
    const dinnerSelect = document.querySelector('#dinnerSelect')
    dinnerSelect.addEventListener('change', () => {
        dinner = parseInt(dinnerSelect.value);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Vanilla JS Clock</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35e4240984.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        
        <h1>What time is it!?</h1>
        <span id="clock">Clock goes here</span>
        
        <div class="icon-wrapper">
        <i id="food-icon" class="fa-5x fas"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="message">
            <p>Hello!</p>
        </div>

        <label>Choose wake up time:</label>
        <select id="wakeSelect">
            <option value="1">1 AM</option>
            <option value="2">2 AM</option>
            <option value="3">3 AM - 4AM</option>
            <option value="4">4 AM - 5AM</option>
            <option value="5">5 AM - 6AM</option>
            <option value="6">6 AM - 7AM</option>
            <option value="7">7 AM - 8AM</option>
            <option value="8" selected>8 AM - 9AM</option>
            <option value="9">9 AM - 10AM</option>
            <option value="10">10 AM - 11AM</option>
            <option value="11">11 AM - 12PM</option>
            <option value="12">12 PM - 1PM</option>
            <option value="13">1 PM - 2PM</option>
            <option value="14">2 PM - 3PM</option>
            <option value="15">3 PM - 4PM</option>
            <option value="16">4 PM - 5PM</option>
            <option value="17">5 PM - 6PM</option>
            <option value="18">6 PM - 7PM</option>
            <option value="19">7 PM - 8PM</option>
            <option value="20">8 PM - 9PM</option>
            <option value="21">9 PM - 10PM</option>
            <option value="22">10 PM - 11PM</option>
            <option value="23">11 PM - 12AM</option>
            <option value="24">12 AM - 1AM</option>
          </select>
        
         <label for="lunchSelect">Choose lunch time</label> 
            <select id="lunchSelect">
              <option value="1">1 AM - 2AM</option>
              <option value="2">2 AM - 3AM</option>
              <option value="3">3 AM - 4AM</option>
              <option value="4">4 AM - 5AM</option>
              <option value="5">5 AM - 6AM</option>
              <option value="6">6 AM - 7AM</option>
              <option value="7">7 AM - 8AM</option>
              <option value="8">8 AM - 9AM</option>
              <option value="9">9 AM - 10AM</option>
              <option value="10">10 AM - 11AM</option>
              <option value="11">11 AM - 12PM</option>
              <option value="12" selected>12 PM - 1PM</option>
              <option value="13">1 PM - 2PM</option>
              <option value="14">2 PM - 3PM</option>
              <option value="15">3 PM - 4PM</option>
              <option value="16">4 PM - 5PM</option>
              <option value="17">5 PM - 6PM</option>
              <option value="18">6 PM - 7PM</option>
              <option value="19">7 PM - 8PM</option>
              <option value="20">8 PM - 9PM</option>
              <option value="21">9 PM - 10PM</option>
              <option value="22">10 PM - 11PM</option>
              <option value="23">11 PM - 12AM</option>
              <option value="24">12 AM - 1AM</option>
            </select>

      

            <label>Choose dinner time</label> 
            <select id="dinnerSelect">
              <option value="1">1 AM - 2AM</option>
              <option value="2">2 AM - 3AM</option>
              <option value="3">3 AM - 4AM</option>
              <option value="4">4 AM - 5AM</option>
              <option value="5">5 AM - 6AM</option>
              <option value="6">6 AM - 7AM</option>
              <option value="7">7 AM - 8AM</option>
              <option value="8">8 AM - 9AM</option>
              <option value="9">9 AM - 10AM</option>
              <option value="10">10 AM - 11AM</option>
              <option value="11">11 AM - 12PM</option>
              <option value="12">12 PM - 1PM</option>
              <option value="13">1 PM - 2PM</option>
              <option value="14">2 PM - 3PM</option>
              <option value="15">3 PM - 4PM</option>
              <option value="16">4 PM - 5PM</option>
              <option value="17">5 PM - 6PM</option>
              <option value="18" selected>6 PM &ndash; 7PM</option>
              <option value="19">7 PM - 8PM</option>
              <option value="20">8 PM - 9PM</option>
              <option value="21">9 PM - 10PM</option>
              <option value="22">10 PM - 11PM</option>
              <option value="23">11 PM - 12AM</option>
              <option value="24">12 AM - 1AM</option>
            </select>
 
   
        <script src="index.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```